# Eigen::DenseBase has no data member

Tags: eigen

Why does `Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>` has no `data()` method?

I thought a dense array would be contiguous in the memory.

Are blocks also DenseBase?

```
template <typename Derived>
void f(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& x) {
    std::sort(x.data(), x.data() + x.size());
}
```

`ArrayBase` also has no data method.

Work around:

```
template <typename Derived>
void f(Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& x) {
    std::sort(&x[0], &x[0] + x.size());  // sort the whole vector
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DenseBase` is the base class for any dense expressions, including `A+B`, `A*B`, etc. If all you want is to call `std::sort`, then move to Eigen's head, and write:

```
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
```

If the expression you passed to `f` has a `.data()` member you can still reach it as follows: `x.derived().data()`.